# SBS 2011 - User Roles appearing as if they're users?

Tags: active-directory, users, windows-sbs-2011

On SBS 2011 Standard, we haven't done any customizations of organizational groups, all that is left default. However, when I'm looking at the Active Directory Users and Computers, under `MyBusiness > Users > SBSUsers`, I'm seeing many of my `Roles` listed mixed in with users, and in the `Type` column, it shows `User`. Why is this?

These roles I had created in the SBS Console. I'm just wondering why they appear as if they were users (and are even called users) in the AD Users and Computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are users. The roles you see in the SBS console are nothing more than "template" user accounts that have membership in particular security groups and have access to particular components, like RWW, etc. and have particular settings, like mailbox and folder quotas.

When you create a new user from the SBS console it uses the "template" user account, based on which role you select, to copy to the new user account.